# Loading image from xcassets causes assertion failure

Tags: ios, swift, xcasset

I am using the xcassets folder to store themable images. For the default theme, the image is always present in the xcassets, but for other themes, the image is optional, which will result in the use of the default image.

Pseudo code:

```
struct ThemeImage {
    static let standard = UIImage(named: "default-logo")!

    static func themedImage(for theme: String) -> UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: "\(theme)-logo") ?? ThemeImage.standard
    }
}
```

Now when I try to load the image for a theme, but the asset does not exist, the app will instantly crash, reporting the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_UIImageCGImageContent initWithCGImage:scale:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3901.4.2/_UIImageContent.m:336
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Need an imageRef'
```

The documentation clearly states

> Returns
>
> An object containing an unconfigured version of the image, or nil if the method could not find the specified image.

Does anyone know what is happening or why the app crashes instead of returning `nil`?

Comment: Did you check that  `UIImage(named: "default-logo")` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, the default image is loaded correctly and is a valid image, i.e. not `nil`

Comment: @Craz1k0ek Your code block seems ok and expected to work here. Can you please confirm that how you are accessing this ThemeImage?

Comment: @RJ168 yeah, I've created another project in the meantime which seems to work. I suppose something fishy is happening in the xcassets settings. Only happens on iOS 13 I've just tested

Comment: @Craz1k0ek I have just checked with 13.3.1 and it is working fine. Can you please specify the exact version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was related to the xcassets folder after all. I had some colours in the folder too, which had the same name as the image.

Meaning `UIColor(named: "default-logo")` and `UIImage(named: "default-logo")` will cause the application to crash, even though both resources are present and valid in the xcassets folder.

The name of these assets needs to be unique.